# Open HTM files in internet Exploer with Java in new tabs

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to open a few HTM files in IE on a windows computer. Earlier I could get them to open sequentially each in a new tab in the same window. Since then I must have changed something small because now it opens each file in a new window.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;

public class OpenFile {
    OpenFile(){
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            p.destroy();

            File folder = new File("C:/Users/SAVAGD05/Documents/RMP/QUERIES/");
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                String url = "C:/Users/SAVAGD05/Documents/RMP/QUERIES/"
                        + listOfFiles[i].getName();
                File htmlFile = new File(url);
                Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlFile.toURI());


            }

        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new OpenFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of code; that makes it far easier to follow.

Comment: @RacilHilan I tried the your approach and I'll go from there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the IE settings (i.e. **Internet Options**) and on the **General** tab, click on the **Tabs** button. Check what the **Open links from other programs in** option is set to (i.e. new window vs. new tab).